# Javascript document.GetElementById('iframe_id').src = 'link' working only once

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

so here's a very simple question but I'm having difficulties on solving it
see i have an iframe and i want to change it's src depending on the link that was clicked

here's the **javascript code**

```
function showOverlay(id)
    {
        var str1 = 'abstract.php?id=';
        var link = str1.concat(id);
        document.getElementById(id).style['display'] = "block";
        document.getElementById(id).style['opacity'] = "1";
        document.getElementById('abstract_frame').src =  link;
    }

    function hideOverlay(el, evt) 
    {
        if (el && evt)
        {
            el.style.display = evt.target == el ? 'none' : '';
        }
        document.getElementById('abstract_frame').src =  '';
    }
```

so I used `document.getElementById('abstract_frame').src =  link;` to set the src then on the hideOverlay function I used
`document.getElementById('abstract_frame').src =  '';` to set the src back to a blank link.

so the problem is when I call on the showOverlay again to set another src link to the iframe with a different value i get a blank screen

here's the **html/php**

```
echo '<div class="SearchResults">';
echo "      <span class='top'>";
echo "          <a>";
echo "              <h3>". strtoupper($title) ."</h3>";
echo "          </a>";
echo "          <br />";
echo "          <h5 class='sub'>";
echo "Authors :";
$tags = explode('|',$run['author']);
foreach($tags as $i =>$key) {

echo '<a class="authors">Dr.'.$key.'</a>';

}
echo "<br><br>";
echo "          </h5>";
echo "      </span>";
echo "      <span class='bottom'>";
echo "          <span class='bottomLeft'>";
echo                    ($run['abstract'] != "" ? "             <a class='options' data-articlenum='" . $run['reference_number'] . "' onclick='showOverlay(this.dataset.articlenum)'>Abstract</a><span style='margin:0px 5px;'>|</span>" : "" );
echo "              <a target='_blank' href='view.php?filename=".strtolower($run['title'])."' class='options'>";
echo "                  Full Article";
echo "              </a>";  
echo "          </span>";
echo "          <div class='overlay' id='". $run['reference_number'] ."' onclick='hideOverlay(this, event)'> ";
echo "              <iframe class='abstract' id='abstract_frame'  style='padding:0px;' scrolling='no'>";    
echo "              </iframe>";
echo "          </div>";
echo "          <span class='bottomRight'>";
echo "              <p class='label'>".$run['journal'].", ". $run['volume'] .", ". date("F, Y",strtotime($run['publication_date']))  ."@ Pg.". $run['pages'] ."</p>";
echo "          </span>";
echo "      </span>";
echo "      <br style='clear:both;'/>";
echo "</div>";
```

here's some visuals

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Inside of showOverlay, console.log your 'link' variable and then console.log your abstract frame .src after you set it. This will help to determine that the link is being passed correctly the second time around

Comment: Umm, this is odd: `if (el && evt) { el.style.display = evt.target == el ? 'none' : ''; }` - `el` is always true once passed the `if` statement, so `el ?` will always select `'none'`.

Comment: @Walker Boh : yes the link  is being passed correctly

but the problem is the src of the iframe doesn't change

Comment: I'm still suspecting it is your link. Make sure that your are passing the full url including http://, otherwise this happens: http://jsfiddle.net/b98w8vqb/

Comment: it doesn't make sense tho, if i complete the link then pass it to the iframe it returns
something like
ctru%20e-library/localhost/abstract......